# Is there a way to replace all spaces outside of pair of two characters in string?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a log file, that I need to make into a csv. For that I need to replace all spaces with `|` character.

My code so far:

```
with open('Log_jeden_den.log', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    line = re.sub(r'[ ]+(?![^[]*\])', '|', line)
```

An example line of this file looks like this:

```
123.456.789.10 - - [20/Feb/2020:06:25:16 +0100] "GET /android-icon-192x192.png HTTP/1.1" 200 4026 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

As you can see, there are spaces inside the `[]` and `""` pairs. Those I **do not** want to replace. Only the spaces outside of them.

I can do this for `[]`, with this regex `[ ]+(?![^[]*\])`, but if I do the same for `""` with similar regex `[ ]+(?![^"]*\")`, it does not work. I tried multiple variations of this regex, none of them worked. What am I missing?

If I work this out, then I would also need to combine those regexes, so I only replace the spaces outside of both character pairs. That would be my second question.

EDIT: Output of my example line as requested:

```
123.456.789.10|-|-|[20/Feb/2020:06:25:16 +0100]|"GET|/android-icon-192x192.png|HTTP/1.1"|200|4026|"-"|"Mozilla/5.0|(Windows|NT|6.1;|WOW64;|Trident/7.0;|rv:11.0)|like|Gecko"
```

EDIT2: This would be my desired output:

```
123.456.789.10|-|-|[20/Feb/2020:06:25:16 +0100]|"GET /android-icon-192x192.png HTTP/1.1"|200|4026|"-"|"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and provide an example output from your example line?

Comment: Are all of the lines in the file of similar structure to the example shown? I.e. do they all contain a first part, a second part inside `[]` and a third part inside `""`?

Comment: @Lucan I have edited the post as you requested.

Comment: @jmd_dk Yes. All lines of the file have the same exact structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
with open('Log_jeden_den_out.log', 'w') as fw:
    with open('Log_jeden_den.log', 'r') as fr:
        for line in fr:
            fw.write( re.sub(r'(\[[^][]*]|"[^"]*")|\s', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else "|", line) )
```

**Details**

- `(\[[^][]*]|"[^"]*")` - Matches and captures into Group 1 any substring between the closest `[` and `]` or `"` and `"`
- `|` - or
- `\s` - just matches any whitespace char in any other context

The `lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else "|"` replacement puts back Group 1 if it matched, else, replaces with a pipe.

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, now that I have more than 15 rep. Again, thank you for your help and the additional information.